# ASP.NET Core empty problems

Tags: asp.net-core

First of all, I apologize for my English. I wanted to make an empty project with ASP.NET Core, but when I wrote `builder.services` in the `program.cs` file, the services cannot be defined and do not work.

I don't know how to fix this error, can you help me?

Comment: We can't help without any code, errors or images. In order for us to be able to say something we need to see what are you facing. So please add your code and the error you are facing. You should read this "https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask" to understand how you should ask questions in the future so that people assist you.

Comment: [Please use `builder.Services` instead of `builder.services`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A77aa.png)

Comment: Please check if you specify and use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` for project in  `.csproj` file, like this `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`.